# How to install Nvidia proprietary drivers on Debian 9 stretch - rc3

Tags: debian

I've been trying to install Nvidia proprietary drivers on Debian 9 stretch - rc3. Without any success.

---

**Why did  I installed testing Debian branch?**

Debian Jessie is kind of outdated for me. I am developing c++ programs on regular basis and I need c++14 / c++17 features (at least g++-6.3). Besides that stretch is in state of full freeze now. And I suspect it will be moved to the stable branch in the nearest future.

---

**Problem description:**

After installing the nvidia graphics card driver from `non-free` Debian repository (followed by laptop reboot), the system is trying to start, but this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAaOL.jpg) occurs.

---

**What did I tried ?**

Everything that I could find with google. Nevertheless i can distinguish this:

**Method #1:**

1. Add `noveau` module to the blacklist  (via `/etc/modprobe.d/nouveau.conf` file)
2. Reboot. After rebooting my computer, I check whether I have disabled the module: `lsmod | grep nouveau`. (it didn't report anything therefore i believe i have succeed).
3. Boot into text mode. Run `apt-get install nvidia-driver` as root.
4. Reboot once again. When X-server starts i get following error: [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAaOL.jpg)

**Method #2:**

1. Same as steps 1, and 2 from method #1.
2. Install `*.run` file dowloaded from official Nvidia site. Result is the same.

**Method #3:**

1. Same as steps 1, 2 and 3 from method #1.
2. Run: `nvidia-xconfig`. Result: broken OS (After reboot I get only blinking cursor)

---

**Information:**

I am kind of new to the linux, so if you would like more specific information, about my problem, please tell me what to do, and I will provide those information.

My root is currently on LVM partition with a snapshot - there is no need to worry about destroying my OS - i will recover it later with LVM.

---

**Edit #1:**

I have performed clean installation of Debian 9 -rc3. Just to be sure that I didn't mess anything. I have completed steps described by *Knud Larsen*. Result is same. I am still getting the same error.

---

**Edit #2:**

It turns out that I am on `hybrid-graphics` system. Problems that I have been experiencing are a result of that. Otherwise answer proposed by *Knud Larsen* would have solved them.

Comment: Maybe the problem is produced because your runing the `nvidia-xconfig` with X server enabled . Try the debian solution https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Backing_out_in_case_of_failure

Comment: @GAD3R I'm sorry I misled you. I did not run `nvidia-xconfig` every time. I run this command only in the "last approach" (or rather I could say, family of approaches)... I have edited my question... Maybe you have other suggestions, ideas??

Comment: Use the official debian documentation https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Backing_out_in_case_of_failure  after runing `Xorg -configure` run `cp xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and reboot

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: @DavidPostill I did NOT crosspost. This question is about installing the drivers on debian system. And i got my answers. I did not get it at first, because my situation was different then i thought. The other question (on the other Stack Exchange site) you are referring to is about different subject. Those two questions, no matter what you are thinking, two separate cases. First questions is about installing divers on Debian, second is about why it is possible to workaround nvidia optimums technology.

Comment: @GAD3R my problem was due to a fact that i am on `hybrid-graphics` system.  See: [NVIDIA Optimus](http://www.nvidia.com/object/optimus_technology.html), or [Bumblebee](https://wiki.debian.org/Bumblebee). Thank you for taking an interest in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian 9 : # `apt-get update && apt install nvidia-driver` : version 375.39 is installed..

Conditions : A line in /etc/apt/sources.list with non-free, like

```
deb http://ftp.funet.fi/pub/linux/mirrors/debian/ stretch contrib non-free
```

Reboot, and you have NVIDIA graphics. (Unless your other actions disturbed something.)

Comment: I have done the following: **(1)** i have formatted my laptop's hard drive. **(2)** I have performed clean installation of Debian 9 -rc3 image downloaded [from here](https://www.debian.org/devel/debian-installer/) - amd64 net-inst **(3)** I copied and pasted your commands. Installation has started. After the installation was complete, I restarted my computer. Here is the [result](http://imgur.com/a/GzMTj)

Comment: Ok it turns out that I have `NVIDIA Optimums` setup. Your Answer does not solves my problem, but it would solve it if i had single GPU system. Therefore I accept your answer as best one.